# Sending a mail using PHPMailer with Gmail Account

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, contact-form

I am trying to send an email from my website using the PHPMailer library. All I did so for was:

1. I downloaded PHPMailer 5.2-stable from [this link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable).
2. I uploaded the following files on my hosting: ***class.phpmailer.php***, ***class.smtp.php*** and ***PHPMailerAutoload.php***
3. Then I created a file name contact.php and wrote the following code in it:

   ```
   require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  

   $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail->Username = "*****************"; //My Email Address
   $mail->Password = "*****************"; //My Email's Address
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";   
   $mail->Port = 578; 

   $mail->AddAddress('*****************');
   $mail->From = "*****************";
   $mail->FromName = "Website Contact Form - " . "Website Name";
   $mail->Subject = "New Message from Contact Form";

   $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';    
   $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
   $mail ->isHTML(true);
   $message = NULL;
   if(!$mail->Send()) {
      $message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   }else{
      $message = "Message sent!";
   }
   ```

But after running this file, I get the following error:

> 2021-06-25 11:44:54 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network
> is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed.

I tried several emails including and email address directly made from my hosting service, a Gmail account and a Google Workspace email (Formerly called, G suit). All of the failed producing the mentioned error.

Finally, I think it is worth to mention that my hosting service does not support PHP's mail() function and that's why I needed to use SMTP.

> Update: After contacting the host and trying a lot, while I am sure
> that I enter the correct username and password, I get the following
> error:

```
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP u21sm391388lfu.60 - gsmtp
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO empiya.com.tr
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [77.245.159.9]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO empiya.com.tr
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [77.245.159.9]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-06-27 12:45:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2021-06-27 12:45:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-06-27 12:45:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu534-5.7.14 vrVLkxbm7_GwFssilR38zKpR_BuczuSM3RIslh77zk6d-DzAo1btUW7FKO8f69tyzO7Fn534-5.7.14 6jydZV9BH6qfEQfpcOfh1z-_V5nn7beFbI0Ekuto0gyBede5j-6dniX9mG6jLWRp>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 u21sm391388lfu.60 - gsmtp
2021-06-27 12:45:20 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu534-5.7.14 vrVLkxbm7_GwFssilR38zKpR_BuczuSM3RIslh77zk6d-DzAo1btUW7FKO8f69tyzO7Fn534-5.7.14 6jydZV9BH6qfEQfpcOfh1z-_V5nn7beFbI0Ekuto0gyBede5j-6dniX9mG6jLWRp>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 u21sm391388lfu.60 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2021-06-27 12:45:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-06-27 12:45:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection u21sm391388lfu.60 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Comment: Try to use SMTP with port number 465, with SMTPSecure => SSL ,  it will work definetly

Comment: @ARVINDIT I tried it, too. It produces the same error.

Comment: Try to delete `$mail->IsSMTP();` and put `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

Comment: I did it, this time I got the following error: "Could not instantiate mail function".

Comment: Don't run 5.2, it's no longer supported. If you comment out `isSMTP`, it will not use SMTP, and will use `mail()` instead, which as you said will not work on your host. Base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and if you have trouble, read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: @Synchro You're right but this example uses composer and I try to write plain PHP code. So when I remove the first three lines of code and run the remaining lines, I get this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ENCRYPTION_SMTPS' in /home/empiyaco/public_html/contactform.php:161 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ..."

Comment: try to use less secure with standard 25 port number with SMTPSecure =>none...

Comment: If you remove the `use` lines, that constant will be referencing something it can't see, as you're finding, so don't do that. Even if you don't use composer, you still need to `use` classes from imported namespaces. There is really no point in avoiding composer; It makes even the simplest projects simpler.

Comment: @ARVINDIT In that case, I get this error: "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed"

Comment: @Synchro composer is not installed on my host, I have to contact the provider.

Comment: No, you can simply run it locally and upload its vendor folder along with all your other PHP files.

Comment: @Synchro I did it and uploaded the vendor folder to my host. This time I get the following error: ""2021-06-25 14:03:57 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: There's a hint in that error message – perhaps you might follow the links to the troubleshooting guide that gives you lots of info about how to diagnose this exact issue? Short version – your hosting provider is probably blocking outbound SMTP.

Comment: So is your problem resolved based on the answers or are you still struggling with it?

Comment: I think the problem is not with the mailer, please check the accounts that you are using. I am not sure but maybe you have Two Factor Authentication turned on for that account, which can prevent you from this type of login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that "less secure app access" setting is turned on for your account.
   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-on-for-your-account
2. Secondly make sure that your host allows to use outgoing port 578, or you can even request them to enable outgoing port.
3. Try using ssl instead of tls, which is more secure and reliable.

Comment: Less Secure Apps feature is turned on already and I have checked the things that you mentioned with my hosting provider.

Comment: You don't need to enable less secure apps; you can use an app-specific password or XOAUTH2. Whether you have a certificate for your web site has absolutely no bearing on whether you use TLS for sending email.

Comment: @Synchro Thankyou, i didn't knew that, for some reason i just thought that you would only use ssl if you would have a certificate :)

Comment: The two encryption modes are only very slightly different (implicit vs explicit), but remember that SSL is simply the old name for TLS, so they are actually both flavours of TLS and the SSL name is only used for historical reasons. The real names when used in email are `SMTPS` and `SMTP+STARTTLS`.

Answer (score 0):

this error commonly shown when SMTP Mail Server Credentials were correct but Application Specific Password was not provided.
and when i had a look to your code i saw that you wrote the port in wrong way which in your code :

```
$mail->Port = 578;
```

while it should be for tls :

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

i hope you found this answer helpful and do not forget to fill

```
$mail->AddAddress('*****************');
$mail->From = "*****************";
```

sections be cause you may have errors if you did not

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that was a typo which has happened while writing the question. In the real code, it is 587 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you have the wrong php mailer i will send you the one that i use and it's working you can check it cause i can't find any problem in your code except as i said that SMTP Mail Server Credentials were correct but Application Specific Password was not provided but i will leave the phpmailer link that i use
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable